# Using the ratio test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I already know that I should do the root test on this series due to the $n$th power, but I want to see if I can establish the result using the ratio test first. (Or would I always be stuck with only one kind of test)

I get something like this: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)^2}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}\right|$$

But then I'm not sure how (or even if I could) simplify this. I've tried on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn+%5Cto+%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B%5Cleft%28n%2B1%5Cright%29%5E2%7D%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7Bn%5E2%7D%7D) to make it simplify but the best I can get is numerical approximations that seem to converge to $e$

Comment: You should expect that: for large $n$ both $\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ and $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ are very close to $e$, so the fraction is approximately $\frac{e^{n+1}}{e^n}=e$.

Comment: Don't use the ratio test. Just observe that $1 + 1/n > 1$, hence $(1 + 1/n)^{n^2} > 1$, and so the terms cannot approach $0$ as $n \to \infty$. That is, it fails the divergence test.

Comment: @TheoBendit The OP seems to know the ratio test is not the way to go (though your argument is simpler than the root test, by far). But that doesn't mean they shouldn't figure out how to apply the ratio test, if they chose to do so anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that
$$
\frac{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}
= 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \tag{1}
$$
We will use that to make the "right" exponent appear, since we want to use the known limit $\lim_{m\to\infty} (1+\frac{u}{m})^m = e^u$.

Now, since $n^2=(n+1)^2-(2n+1)$, we can rewrite
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)^2}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}
&= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+1}\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}
= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+1} \left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n^2} \\
&= \color{red}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\cdot \color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{2}{2n}\right)^{2n}}\cdot \color{green}{\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}} \tag{2}
\end{align*}$$
This is great! We know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) = \color{red}{1} \tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{2n}\right)^{2n} = \color{blue}{e^{2}} \tag{4}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{(n+1)^2} = \color{green}{e^{-1}} \tag{5}
$$
so, combining (3), (4), and (5) into (2), we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\left(n+1\right)^2}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}
= \color{red}{1} \cdot \color{blue}{e^{2}} \cdot \color{green}{e^{-1}} = \boxed{e}
$$

Answer (score 1):

To find the limit $$ \begin{align}\displaystyle  \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n^{2}}} \cdot \dfrac{\left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{(n+1)^2}}{\left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{(n+1)^2}} &= \left( \dfrac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} \right)^{(n+1)^2} \cdot \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{2n+1} \\
&= \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^{(n+1)^2} \cdot \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{2n+1} \end{align} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\implies \log(a_n)=n^2 \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Now, by Taylor
$$\log(a_n)=n-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3 n}-\frac{1}{4 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Apply it a second time and continue with Taylor
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=1-\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} }{a_n }=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=e-\frac{e}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$